# Is it possible to style posts in octopress according to its tags?

Tags: css, jekyll, octopress

I need to style all the posts in Octopress which have the tag 'old' differently. Like, show only the title and no image in archives and keep them separated! How can I do this? (Note : There are nearly 1,500 posts with the old tag)

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have a `old` class that differentiates the posts or that you can style a list of old posts with a `old_posts` class. You can create two separate lists:

```
<ul class="old_posts">
    {% for post in site.tags.old %}
        <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<ul class="new_posts">
    {% for post in site.posts %}
        {% unless post.tags contains 'old' %}
            <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}    
</ul>
```

Or you can create one list with the old posts receiving a special class `old`:

```
<ul>
  {% for post in site.posts %}
      {% if post.tags contains 'old' %}
          <li><a href="{{ post.url }}" class="old">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
      {% else %}
          <li><a href="{{ post.url }}" class="new">{{ post.title }}</a></li>          
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Basically, `site.posts`, `post.tags` and `site.tags.TAGNAME`, together with Liquid's `if-else`, `for` and `contains` are able to do most of the tasks related to styling specifically tagged posts.

Comment: There's one small problem. The code doesn't work. It take posts with the tag old to the normal post list. It doesn't recognize the old tag. I think its because one post have multiple tags. How to fix this? How to search for a sub-string 'old' in post.tags?

Comment: Fixed! use 'old' instead of old!

Comment: That's great :) Sorry, I was on my way to work so there wasn't a way to test the code. Btw, if my answer helped you, can you assign it as the top answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the tags as css classes:

```
<ul>
  {% for post in site.posts %}      
      <li><a href="{{ post.url }}" class="tags {{ post.tags | join:' ' }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>     
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

That way you can style the link easily via css for any tag.